# Capturar datos del gps con JAVA

Tags: java, socket

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para mostrar datos de unos gps en web, pero no me queda claro el tema de capturar las tramas

Quisiera hacer un socket en java pero no tengo claro como hacerlo, para que este corra en segundo plano y me capture los datos de los gps.

Comment: Hola Mario, bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu pregunta es **muy amplia** porque en este sitio se resuelven dudas y problemas trabajados previamente. Has de investigar mejor como hacerlo e intentarlo. Si en el desarrollo tienes problemas o errores, entonces preguntar eso particularmente, no algo tan abierto. Recuerda leer el [tour] y [ask] para aprender sobre el sitio y como hacer preguntas de mayor calidad. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Yo le haría de esta manera:

```
package ejemplo.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServidorEscucha {


    public ServidorEscucha() throws Exception{


        InetAddress hostIp;
        hostIp = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"); // O la que necesites

        ServerSocket escuchar = new ServerSocket(1234, 1000, hostIp); // Puerto 1234 o el que requieras abrir
        try {
            while (true) {
                new AtenderCliente(escuchar.accept()).start();
            }
        } finally {
            escuchar.close();
        }
    }

    private static class AtenderCliente extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;

        public AtenderCliente(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {

                // Preparamos el buffer para leer la data de los GPS
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                // Leeemos linea a linea lo que envíe el GPS
                while (true) {
                    String TramaEntrante = in.readLine();
                    if (TramaEntrante == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    // Procesar la trama entrada como se requiera
                    // *** PARSEAR / ALMACENAR EN DB  ***********
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en cliente: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("No se pudo cerrar el puerto: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                System.out.println("Conexión con cliente cerrada.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```